# Is dhrishti discussed any time in hinduism?

Tags: puranas

Is dhrishti real?

It become routine to take precautions while I am planning to fulfil any of my wish just because I am concerned of dhrishti.

Do we have any stories about dhrishti

Comment: think of drishti as yet another obstacle that you need to cross in the game of life. yes, people may feel jealous of you, it just means you need to work harder and keep it secret.

Comment: If you mean evil eye then it's there and they also discuss the methods of removing it's effect. The methods involve the use of Yantras etc.

Comment: @Rickross Do you know some scriptures which discuss about evil eye, causes , harms , remedies,etc. This is a very interesting thing for me as till now, I only thought of it as a superstition 

Comment: I have some compendium books on Tantras that have separate sections on evil eye problems and Mantras and Yantras based solutions .. So obviously there are possibly some Tantric scriptures that discuss it but I don't know their names ...evil eye is problematic particularly for new born kids. I don't think it affects grown ups that much as they affect the kids. @LSSJBroly